# How to create IOS 5.1 apps in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, landscape

I encounter landscape orientation issues when I create Ipad apps for IOS 5  on Xcode 4.5
I saw few related question  but most of them are opposite of my situation.

I dont' use any code like `Bool autorotate` I just choose landscape on interface builder. Use autolayout is deselected.

When I create app I choose IOS Deployment Target 5.1 on project folder(blue icon)

[image]

**Build settings is architecture Base Sdk is IOS 6**

[image]

**In storyboard navigation controller is set to landscape and interface document is set to 5.1**

[image]

**In IOS 6 simulator landscape works well:**

[image]

**But in IOS 5.1 Simulator landscape does not work and disorientated**

[image]

*What am I missing ? How can I make this work for both 5.1 and 6 versions?*

EDIT=====

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Above code does not work either. It is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: on the view controller and return YES for your desired orientations, for example

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

}

Comment: edited question I actually tried that before I post the question and still does not work

Comment: You set the supported interface orientations to landscape only, right?

Comment: On storyboard -> simulated metrics -> orientation is set to Landscape

Comment: Ok now overriding method in the root controller of navigation controller made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Before IOS 6.0 you have to override this method on all ViewControllers of your project. In IOS 6 finally Apple did correct this behavior

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Update all your view controllers with the following code.

Works in Simulator 5.0 and up.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```